# How to change the layout of an app to LandScape and how to make the layout of an app adaptable to mobile and tablets

Tags: android, android-layout, landscape

I'm new to android and I would like my app that when it is opened, it's orientation or layout is changed to landscape, just like in some games I downloaded from the Play Store. I also want to know to how to make my app have the ability to adapt its layout whether it is installed in a mobile phone (around 4 inches in screen size) and a tablet (like samsung galaxy tab 2 7.0). I just recently installed an app I created in our tablet and its layout changed, 2 buttons are on top of each other and a textview is covering another button because I found out that the layout I created is for a mobile phone.

I hope someone can give me a detailed explanation and example on this.

Many thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically what you can do is avoid the use of static dimensions. This is the main reason of your problem. Make the use of wrap_content or match_parent and if you are using LinearLayout then adjust components through weights and if you are using RelativeLayout then adjust the components with respect to each other and for all these you will have to go through layouts throughly and learn the use of dimen.xml.

Go through [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)...

Comment: I kinda understand what you said. I'll read the details in the link you posted thanks!

Comment: Welcome. If you like it then accept my answer/up vote me. And locking the orientation to portrait is not solving the problem,its running away from it because if not now then later you will have to learn that too,so why not do it now.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I suggest that you should read [Support For Multiple Screen](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).And forcing your app to open in landscape or portrait mode you set it in your `AndroidMenifest.xml` file like below.

```
  <activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" ></activity>
```

Hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: Yes that is good place to understand the UI designing in android :)